# solr search results don't return as expected if the highlight field contains html flag

Tags: solr, coldfusion, highlight, coldfusion-10

I am using **setHighlightSimplePre** and **setHighlightSimplePost** to change the default <em> to <strong>, setting the text which appears around a highlighted term.

My search keyword is 'Testing for Add SON'. I got confused when the returned data displayed all in bold. Then I dumped the data out and found that it returned incorrectly. The </p> has been separated as below:

```
<p><strong>Testing</strong> for <strong>Add</strong> <strong>SON</p</strong>>
```

**Then the contents after the flag all turned to be bold text.**

Has anyone else ever had this problem?

**Note: I am using Solr 3.4 built on ColdFusion 10.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the text you are searching contain HTML? If so, that is the problem, you should strip out HTML before indexing.

Comment: I wonder if, when the data are indexed for searching, they are being tokenized correctly? It looks like Solr thinks `Add</p` and `SON</p` are tokens whose stems are `Add` and `SON` respectively.

Comment: @ScottStroz Just search for 'Testing for Add SON', no html in it.

Comment: @DavidFaber Can you tell me the right way to find out whether the data are being tokenized correctly? I got this via admin/analysis.jsp, Input the field name and search key word, then click Analysis, is this the right way? I'm new to solr.

Comment: @DavidFaber If I search via solr/admin/form.jsp, input the keywords, enable hightlight and input the hightlight field that contains &lt;/p&gt;, the data returned correctly. But the data return via solr query is incorrect. I got confused.

Comment: No, I meant in the index/text that is being searched, not the search term used. The problem is that Solr does not know from HTML, so, when it grabs a snippet of text for the 'context' it has no idea that there is an opening paragraph tag and not a closed one. The solution is to strip out any HTML BEFORE you index the data - which is a good idea anyway, could lead to false positives.. This way, it will be clean when it is returned from Solr.

Comment: @ScottStroz Many thanks. Striping out html tags works good for me.